# Функция mail() не работает через cron

Tags: php, cron

Скрипт проверяет файлы и отправляет отчет функцией mail(). Если запускать через браузер - все ок. При запуске через cron скрипт всё выполняет(в файле лога скрипта добавляются записи о работе), но почта не отправляется. 
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Может что в логах ошибок есть? Что будет, если вручную запустить крон, покажутся ли ошибки? Можно поиграться с `mail()` - написать простейший скрипт из одной этой функции и посмотреть как он будет работать.

Comment: @IvanBolnikh вручную запустить возможности нет - только указывать через панель хостера Godaddy. Скрипт из одной функции тоже не работает через крон, хотя через браузер все ок.

Comment: Ошибки от  работы скрипта не выводит? Может надо обратиться с поддержку или ЧАВО почитать.

Comment: @IvanBolnikh поддержки в годедди нет(точнее есть, но на английском языке и только по телефону) . В ЧАВО решения нет. В логах крона тоже нет ошибок. Нашел решение здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20880724/cron-job-to-send-mail-with-godaddy-shared-host